# MsSql: How to pass a parameter in query in the 'LIKE' Operator instead of a static value

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I pass a parameter in query instead of static value in the LIKE operator?

[image]

My table would be like this

The query i am currently using is:

```sql
Select  Url from UrlTable where Url LIKE  '%customer%' ;
```

Comment: If you're using something like Java or C# with your SQL Server instance, you could create a prepared statement there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables to assign values to them. Passing then into a stored procedure is a common process and the syntax is below.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test(@Customer NVARCHAR(150))
AS
    Select  Url from UrlTable where Url LIKE  '%'+@Customer+'%'
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but in my case am limited in access for using stored procedure, instead is there any other way than Stored Procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following;

```
DECLARE @Customer nvarchar(50) = [value_to_filter];

Select  Url from UrlTable where Url LIKE  '%' + @customer + '%';
```